# Gnome on Wayland won't start on Ubuntu. How do I make it run?

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, wayland

When I select "GNOME Wayland" from the LightDM Unity Greeter on Ubuntu 17.10 and try to log in, the screen goes black for a few seconds before popping me back into the greeter (and I think the cursor might get switched to the breeze cursor, too.) Regular GNOME and GNOME Classic work fine, and it seems that launching Plasma on Wayland does too, but GNOME Wayland simply won't start.

How can I make it actually work? Am I missing a package for it?

Comment: Ask here as ask ubuntu doesn't 'like' questions about dev versions of Ubuntu. https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427

Comment: @doug it didn't work back when I used the current LTS, either, so I don't think using dev has anything to do with it.